# Finding an element in a list and setting it as the first element

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I'm working with asp.net web api and I have a `file.Json` with a couple of books.

I want to be able to do for example `port/api/books/title/deploy` and then show all the books but have the book with that title as the first.

This is what I have tried most recently.

```
[HttpGet("author/{author}")]
public IActionResult GetBookByAuthor(string author)
{
    var book = GetBookObjectByAuthor(author);
    if (book is null) return NotFound();
    return Ok(book);
}

private IEnumerable<Book> GetBookObjectByAuthor(string author)
{
    var sortByAuthor = _bookList.Where(_bookList => _bookList.Author.CaseInsensitiveContains(author));
    _bookList.Remove(sortByAuthor);
    _bookList.Insert(0, sortByAuthor);
    return _bookList;
}
```

I dont have any issue finding one author's book and displaying it. But I'm trying to show all books but with the searched author at the top.  When I do this way it says `cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<projectname.Controllers.BooksController.Book>' to 'projectname.Controllers.BooksController.Book'` on the `_bookList.remove` & `_bookList.Insert` rows.

How do I do this the right way? I can provide more code if something else is needed.

Comment: `.Where` returns a collection, whereas `.Insert` requires a single element. Simplest way to fix it is to remove the call to `insert` and rewrite your return statement to this: `return sortByAuthor.Concat(_bookList);`. However, this may not be safe since you've decided to make `_bookList` a field. In this case you would have to loop through all the books in the `sortByAuthor` collection and insert them at the start of `_bookList`.

Comment: @filipman16 Do you want to return ALL books of the author? Or just one?

Comment: @WoIIe I just added a comment to your post where I believe I might be going at the question the wrong way. But anyhow, if an actor has multiple books I want to return ALL books from them.

Comment: Why do people put dislike's on a question like this, without giving any input? I am trying to learn, and understand what I am doing wrong. Then somebody comes along, dislikes the question and decreases the possibilities for me to actually learn when getting restricted on my account. Amazing..!

Comment: I should stress I didnt downvote your question (FWIW my answer also got downvoted). But some hints - your question is a little muddled, you talk about titles yet the code looks like its referencing authors. The error message is pretty self explanatory if you read the docs of `Where` which obviously returns an `IEnumerable<List>` whereas `Insert` and `Remove` expect a single `Book` instance. Final advice, put yourself in the reader/answerers shoes - could you read this question and answer it given all the knowledge in the world or is it vague/ambiguous?

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks alot for the input! I figured very shortly after submitting the question, It's unclear what I'm asking. I knew the issue with the error message. My point was, how do I do it the correct way. And therefore that might be unnecessary information. The part about titles & authors is correct. That's an error from me, where I should've given more precise information. Once again thank you, I will keep this in mind. If you dont mind looking at the comment on `Wolle` I could use somebody else's input. I might be interpreting this the wrong way.

Comment: @filipman16 see if this helps you: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eOrIkO

Answer (score 1):

If you return and Enumerable, ordered descending by your condition, all elements fullfilling this condition will be at the beginning of method result IEnumerable.

```
private IEnumerable<Book> GetBookObjectByAuthor(string author)
{
    return _bookList.OrderByDescending(_bookList => _bookList.Author.CaseInsensitiveContains(author));
}
```

Comment: @filipman16 I dont understand your question on this answer - it seems like you're asking this answerer what _your app should do_ - Surely you know what it should do?

Comment: @Jamiec Maybe it's wrong asking this question on his answer? I believe it is so actually. I will delete them. Although to clarify, my question was whether I should return only the books with authors containing "joe", or all the books but with "joe" at the top. It's not really my app, it's a practice task. But I am pretty sure I know what to do now. So I am sorry for all the clutter in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Except()` and `InsertRange()` to remove a list from another list and insert a list at the specify position of another list

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 3, 4, 5 };
list1 = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
list1.InsertRange(0, list2);
```